# R: optim() cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r

I am learning using optim() in R, and tried to write my own first example like below:

```
fgg<-function(a,params){
  5*params[1]+5*params[2]^2-a
}
result<-optim(params= c(1, 1),fgg, a=1)
```

But when I run this code, I get an error like this:
  **cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'**
I see several other examples and I didn't find any difference btw the structure of my code and the one of those examples.

Can anyone give me an idea about where I did wrong? thank you guys so much!

Comment: Add parameter values for the first argument `par` in `optim`

Comment: @HaoxingBai: please post and accept your own answer.